# jquery enable/disable form field section based on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

```
<form name="form" aDisabled="true" bDisabled="false">
<fieldset id="a">
<input> 
...
</fieldset>
<fieldset id="b">
<input> 
...
</fieldset>
</form>
```

So i want to make the fields under fieldset to be disabled when aDisabled is true and b to remain enabled, i tried the below jquery but this does not seem to work for me

```
$("[aDisabled='true'] input:not('#b')").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can disable all `fieldset`'s inside your form except `#b` like this

```js
$("[aDisabled='true'] fieldset:not(#b)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" aDisabled="true" bDisabled="false">
  <fieldset id="a">
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="b">
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: $("[aDisabled='true'] fieldset:not(#b)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" aDisabled="true" bDisabled="false">
  <fieldset id="a">
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
    <input type="text">
</form> actually i have like this, there is just one fieldset

Comment: I don't understand your comment, can you create https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/ with your actual `HTML` and say what you want to disable.

Comment: i said what if there is no fieldset id="b" , there are just input fields in fieldset id="a" and some input fields directly inside form

Comment: Then you just select and disable `fieldset` with id `a` https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/753/ or if you want to select specific element inside that `fieldset` you target them like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/755/

Comment: yea but how do you inverse the condition than, disable the one that are at form level and not enable the one's under fieldset id="a"?

Comment: yea but its not all about aDisabled (not an if else statement), i need to check both simultaneously, they can both have any value

Comment: ok i'll make it simple, why does this statement not work?  $('form > *:not(#a) input').attr('disabled', true);

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your selector is that input:not(#a) means "input without an ID of a" which is true for all your inputs. 
What you meant is "fieldset:not(#a)" or more accurately, "fieldset#b"

```
$("[aDisabled='true'] fieldset#a input").attr('disabled', true);
$("[bDisabled='true'] fieldset#b input").attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: lets say i don't have fieldset id=b. how would i filter all except fieldset id=a?

Comment: `fieldset:not(#a)` as mentioned above.